How to bevel/fatten a complex object to make it sloped?
I want to turn a mesh of an extruded 2d image into a pattern for a mooncake which would require it to have a slope towards the top. I have tried using bevel tool/modifier and that didn't work. Shrink/Fatten got me closer but it made the model too messy to work with. I can't think of anything else.
Edit: Like how subdivision surface will turn a cylinder into a weird looking trapezohedron, I want to use a similar effect to remove the sharp edges from the text and extruded lines.
This is what I started with:

This is what I currently have:

The file is linked here

Hi, DingBong, welcome. Could you show us what you mean by 'slope towards the top' ? Is that a domed cap to a pastry? Is this shape intended to be a raised relief on the surface? Do you need the geometry, or is this for visual effect? (You may, for example, be able to use a bump-map)

If you want a domed effect, try selecting a vertex as close to the centre of your object as possible, turning on Proportional Editing with the 'O' (O, not zero) key and then using G > Z to move it up scrolling the mouse wheel to affect the area of influence.

By slope up towards the top I want basically to round out all of the lettering and lines on one side, both sides would be fine as well. The second image reflects what I want but I guess I should have angled the camera. Basically I want the lettering to appear from the side like a bump so it can stamp into dough

I don’t think proportional editing would work easily in this case, but I’m thinking ungrouping by distance and manually tweaking all of them might be the only way it would just take hours.

I tried using the shrink wrap modifier on the top of it to only get the geometry appearing in the second photo, but blender couldn’t figure out what to do with it and it wouldn’t work.

Like this? https://i.imgur.com/qnjiB9F.jpeg or this? https://i.imgur.com/KuAvRAc.png

Like the first link, https://imgur.com/qnjiB9F, that would be perfect.

Is a lattice modifier what you need? Add a 'cage' object around your mesh and deforming the cage will deform the object contained in it.
